# Autohotkey - how to store unicode and use it?

Tags: unicode, autohotkey

Here's my code below. AHK file is saved as UTF-8 with BOM and I can see the unicode characters just fine whenever I paste it into the script. But everytime I save the script and re-open it, the unicode characters become question marks and random gibberish characters. When "sendinput" is run, the output also comes out as question marks and gibberish, instead of the actual unicode emoticons.

```
MyVarEmoticon =
      (Ltrim
         What is your choice? (Enter #):

         1. (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻
         
         2. (┛ಠ_ಠ)┛彡┻━┻
         
         3. (╯°Д°)╯︵/(.□ . \)

         4. ┏━┓┏━┓┏━┓ ︵ /(^.^/)

      )


InputBox, MyVarEmoticonChoices, Emoticon Choices, %MyVarEmoticon%, , 400, % HEmoticon(MyVarEmoticon),,,,,1
          
HEmoticon(MyVarEmoticon)
    {
     StringReplace, MyVarEmoticon,myvaremoticon,`n,`n,UseErrorLevel
     Lines:=ErrorLevel+1
     height:=lines * 30 ; play with this value !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
     ;MsgBox % height
     If (Height < 40) ; too low 
        Height+=80
     Return height
    }   

if ErrorLevel {
        ;MsgBox, CANCEL was pressed.
    
} else {    

    
    if (MyVarEmoticonChoices = "1"){
        MyVarEmoticonChoices = (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻
    }
    if (MyVarEmoticonChoices = "2"){
        MyVarEmoticonChoices = (┛ಠ_ಠ)┛彡┻━┻
    }
    if (MyVarEmoticonChoices = "3"){
        MyVarEmoticonChoices = (╯°Д°)╯︵/(.□ . \)
    }
    if (MyVarEmoticonChoices = "4"){
        MyVarEmoticonChoices = ┏━┓┏━┓┏━┓ ︵ /(^.^/)
    }

        WinGetPos, X, Y, Width, Height, ahk_exe ToW.exe, , ,
        XVar = %X%
        YVar = %Y%
        WVar = %Width%
        HVar = %Height%
        XWVar = % XVar+39
        YHVar = % YVar+682
                                    
        Sleep,200
        sendinput, {raw}%MyVarEmoticonChoices%
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there are some quite weird things in this code, it seems to work as expected if saved with the correct encoding.
I can't really know what goes wrong when you're trying to save it, maybe try to explain the steps you take to save it in the editor you're using.

If you don't want to worry about file encoding, you could store the characters as code points for example.
You can find a quick little converter with a Google search, here is the one I landed on with a Google search:
http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%28%E2%95%AF%C2%B0%E2%96%A1%C2%B0%29%E2%95%AF%EF%B8%B5+%E2%94%BB%E2%94%81%E2%94%BB
And then you can convert to the code points to characters with [`Chr()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Chr.htm).

For example:

```
emote := "0028 256F 00B0 25A1 00B0 0029 256F FE35 0020 253B 2501 253B"
for each, codepoint in StrSplit(emote, " ")
   output .= Chr("0x" codepoint)

Clipboard := output
SendInput, ^v
```

And here I'm also utilizing the clipboard and sending <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, which is a good trick if you can use it. Especially for long text, which this really isn't I guess, but I figured I'd show it.

Or if you want to `Send` the string, you can use the [Unicode notation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Unicode):

```
emote := "0028 256F 00B0 25A1 00B0 0029 256F FE35 0020 253B 2501 253B"
for each, codepoint in StrSplit(emote, " ")
   output .= "{U+" codepoint "}"

SendInput, % output
;SendInput, % "{U+0028}{U+256F}{U+00B0}{U+25A1}{U+00B0}{U+0029}{U+256F}{U+FE35}{U+0020}{U+253B}{U+2501}{U+253B}"
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I found out what the issue is. If I test sendinput against Notepad, it works fine for both my original method and your method. However, in the program that I'm trying to use this for, it's not working, so there must be something specific with that software. I ended up using my method and just copy the MyVarEmoticonChoices  into my clipboard and then do a send paste. So it looks like:



MyVarEmoticonChoices  := (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻
clipboard := MyVarEmoticonChoices 
send, ^v

Answer (score 0):

In ahk script files you must choose **`UTF-16 LE BOM`** Encoding to support Unicode characters. That's a Microsoft Windows default behaviour which indicates all other encodings as ASCII.